# Layout is not changed in top pannel (using a gnome-tweaks) [22.04]

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

If I tap `Alt+Shift` my layout change but I don't see it on my pannel and I don't know what layout coicing now. I use `gnome-tweaks` for change shortcuts from `Super+Space` to `Alt+Shift`.

[It is my gnome-tweaks settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAwhK.jpg)

[If I tap Alt+Shift keyboard language changed but not on my top panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B9vo.jpg)

But if I choice single key shortkate like Left Alt or Shift in my gnome-tweaks setting, switching worked correctly

How I can fix it?
Thank You!

Comment: This is [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916). Please feel free to state that it affects you, and also to add a comment if you have anything to add to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or assign another shortcut in Settings - Keyboard to switch the keyboard layout if you prefer that the indicator on the panel works correctly. As you see, with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, it does not work. It would, however, work, if you for example used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (modifier keys *and* a regular key).

Unless you know how to edit source code, you cannot fix that yourself. You could file this as an issue to the Gnome Shell developers so this may be made to work one day.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I did thik gnome-tewaks fix it problem, but not:) Possibly you know where I can change source code?